# Restart azure identity management access review

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, cloud, azure-security, azure-identity

I have some access reviews for Azure groups created as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/create-access-review.

These access reviews must be reviewed yearly and have a duration of 7 days. [image]

I missed some and now the review is finished, with a status of "not reviewed". I cannot find an option to reschedule or restart this review, the next review is in 1 year. I would like to review again sooner. Is it possible? I cannot find an option to do this.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK Once review done you can't reschedule or restart this review. Either you have to create it again or you can use Azure Policy to automate the review process.

Answer (score 1):

```
I cannot find an option to reschedule or restart this review, the next review is in 1 year. I would like to review again sooner. Is it possible?
```

**AFAIK Once review done you can't reschedule or restart this review.**

Maybe the alternative is if user not reviewed then you can remove the users by

navigate to Azure Active Directory > Security > Access reviews.

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/access-reviews-external-users) it may helps.

If it's possible try to remove those users who are not reviewed, then you can create new access reviews for those users.